# Expression and Automapper

Tags: c#, reflection

Somewhere in the internet I found below class which I am using to convert `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` from DTO to Domain:

```
public class EvaluateVariableVisitor<TEntity, TDto> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _dtoParameter;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _entityParameter;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public EvaluateVariableVisitor()
    {
        _entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        _dtoParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDto));
        _mapper = AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        try
        {
            //change dto to entity type.
            if (node.Expression.Type == _dtoParameter.Type)
            {
                var reducedExpression = Visit(node.Expression);

                //TypeMap typeMap = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<TDto, TEntity>();
                TypeMap typeMap = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<TDto, TEntity>();

                //find the correct name of the property in the destination object by using the name of the source objekt
                string destinationPropertyName = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps() //GetCustomPropertyMaps()
                                                        .Where(propertyMap => propertyMap.SourceMember.Name == node.Member.Name)
                                                        .Select(propertyMap => propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name).FirstOrDefault();


                //find the correct name of the property in the destination object by using the name of the source objekt
                //string destinationPropertyName = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps() //GetCustomPropertyMaps()
                //                                        .Where(propertyMap => propertyMap.SourceMember.Name == node.Member.Name)
                //                                        .Select(propertyMap => propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name).Single();

                var newMember = _entityParameter.Type.GetMember(destinationPropertyName).First();

                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(reducedExpression, newMember);
            }

            //Recurse down to see if we can simplify...
            var expression = Visit(node.Expression);

            //If we've ended up with a constant, and it's a property or a field,
            //we can simplify ourselves to a constant
            var constantExpression = expression as ConstantExpression;
            if (constantExpression != null)
            {
                object container = constantExpression.Value;
                object value = null;

                var memberAsFieldInfo = node.Member as FieldInfo;
                var memberAsPropertyInfo = node.Member as PropertyInfo;

                if (memberAsFieldInfo != null)
                {
                    value = memberAsFieldInfo.GetValue(container);
                }

                if (memberAsPropertyInfo != null)
                {
                    value = memberAsPropertyInfo.GetValue(container, null);
                }

                if (value != null)
                {
                    return Expression.Constant(value);
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            var ex = exc.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }

    //change type from dto to entity --> otherwise the generated expression tree would throw an exception, because of missmatching types(Dto can't be used in Entity expression).
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node.Type == _dtoParameter.Type ? _entityParameter : node;
    }
}
```

It was working great but I faced an issue when I had property of the same type inside my DTO:

```
  public class InventoryApplicationDto
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name{ get; set; }
      public InventoryApplicationDto ParentApplication { get; set; }    
  }
```

First of all I had to change:

```
string destinationPropertyName = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps() 
    .Where(propertyMap => propertyMap.SourceMember.Name == node.Member.Name)
    .Select(propertyMap => propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name).Single();
```

To:

```
string destinationPropertyName = typeMap.GetPropertyMaps() 
    .Where(propertyMap => propertyMap.SourceMember.Name == node.Member.Name)
    .Select(propertyMap => propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

My problem is that I am getting error:

> System.ArgumentException: Property 'Int32 ID' is not defined for type
>   'InventoryApplicationDto'

on line:

```
return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(reducedExpression, newMember);
```

Is MakeMemberAccess method case sensitive or there is another issue?

Comment: Do you know why its looking for `ID` instead of `Id`? I think in your domain object the property is named `Id`

Comment: My Domain property is ID. Does it mean it is the cause of this error?

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant that your domain object property is most likely `ID`. Yes that is the problem because if you read the error carefully it is looking for the the property `ID` in your DTO but it cannot find it because it is `Id`. You need to make sure both objects have the same property including case.

Comment: Is it possible to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I changed  property in my DTO class to public Int32 ID { get; set; } but still the same error occurs.

Comment: Yes off course but I wouldn't do that. I rather have the same cases unless the code is not withing my control. You would change this line: `.Where(propertyMap => propertyMap.SourceMember.Name.ToLower() == node.Member.Name.ToLower())` (see how I added ToLower() to it.)

Comment: @CodingYoshi It didn't help. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Rather than *a code somewhere from the internet*. why don't you try the [Expression Translation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource)) provided by Auto Mapper out of the box.

Comment: @IvanStoev - please check my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370424/automaper-for-collections-of-expressionfunc - I already tried this but I face another problem.